# Add JLabel dynamically in a JPanel (revalidate didn't work)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I have a method that tries to add labels dynamically in  JPanel in  the PackingByVolDialog class:

```
public static void addContent( String content, String container) {

        contentPanel = new JPanel();
        changingLabel = new JLabel(); 
        changingLabel.setText(container+"\n"+content);
        contentPanel.add(changingLabel);
        contentPanel.revalidate();
        contentPanel.repaint();
        dialog.add(contentPanel);
    }
```

and in an other class , I call the `addContent` method as follows:

```
for (int u=0; u<containers.size()-1; u++) {

          PackingByVolDialog.addContent(content, container);

                 } //end for
```

This is the MCVE (?) I was asked to make ( I hope it's correct and helpful)

```
public class VolDialog extends JDialog {

    private static JLabel label = new JLabel() ;
    private static JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private static VolDialog dialog = new VolDialog(); 


  public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
             dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
             dialog.add(contentPanel);
             dialog.revalidate();
             dialog.repaint();
            dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


 public static void addContent( String text) {

    contentPanel = new JPanel();
    changingLabel = new JLabel(); 
    changingLabel.setText(text);
    contentPanel.add(changingLabel);
    }


 public class content {

       for (int u=0; u<N; u++) {

               VolDialog.addContent("text");

             } //end for
          }
```

even when using `repaint` and `revalidate` of the JPanel, only the last output is displayed in the window.

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: Why do you call revalidate and repaint before you add the panel to the dialog (there will be no effect, since the contentPanel is not yet visible)? And you need to revalidate the dialog, not the contentPanel.

Comment: This code just doesn't look right, including use of static swapping JPanel with JLabel , avoidance of CardLayout -- to get the best help, please create and post a valid [mcve] so we can really see what is going on. Please read the link before posting.

Comment: *"I have a method that tries to add labels dynamically.."* Here's a thought. Keep the panel just the same, don't refresh it each time. Keep the same label a well, just ***change the label text!***

Comment: @FredK : I changed the code and did the revalidate to the dialog then called it after adding the panel to the dialog just like you said! But nothing changed , same display.

Comment: @AndrewThompson How can I changed the label text? It's what I want to display, is there another way to do so?

Comment: *"How can I changed the label text?"* I'll look into it more closely when you post the MCVE suggested by @HovercraftFullOfEels .. When is that due to appear?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Do I post the MCVE in a new follow up post or in the same question?

Comment: Just [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36987484/edit)..

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I edited my question

Comment: How can that be an example of a run-time problem when it does not even compile? An MCVE needs a class definition, imports and a `main` method to put it on-screen. When you think you have one, paste it into a new project in your IDE, compile it, run it, and check the problem is displayed. Then be sure to use the shortcut the IDE defines for 'format the code' before editing the question to add it. Or as I typically put it in a copy/paste comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: It's my first time writing an MCVE and I was in a rush because I don't have time at all to write new codes.
The project I am doing is too big and complicated and to make a small example of MCVE out of it is not an easy task. I hope you understand.  
 I will try to make another one if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> The project I am doing is too big and complicated

Which is why you always need to create and post an MCVE when asking a question. We don't have time to look at and understand your entire project. It is up to you to understand the problem you are asking about and then simplify the code to duplicate the problem. Many times when you do this you will find your problem. If not, then you have a simple piece of code to post.

> it is not an easy task.

Once you do it a couple of times, like anything in life, it becomes easier and easier.

> I was in a rush because I don't have time at all to write new codes

Well you should still produce well structured and designed code. It takes no more time to create an MVCE properly using normal Swing coding conventions.

For example:

1. You should not be extending JDialog. All you are doing is adding components to the dialog so in the main() method you just create the dialog.
2. You should not be using static variables and methods. This indicates poor design of the code.
3. Class names should start with an upper case character
4. Your code doesn't compile.
5. You never create a new instance of the "content" class, so the addContent(...) method is never invoked. So this mean you never even tested the code you posted.

When you ask the question YOU need to take the time to do things properly and give us the information we need to solve the problem.

> only the last output is displayed in the window.

The default layout manager of Swing frames and dialogs is a `BorderLayout`. You can only add a single component to the "CENTER" of the BorderLayout (which is the default when you don't specify a constraint).

So basically you need to change the layout manager of the dialog. Try changing:

```
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
```

to see the difference.

If you need more help then post a proper MCVE. One that actually compiles and is well designed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and pieces of advice!
I have already fixed the problem and it works perfectly fine now.

Comment: Well, you should be telling us this BEFORE we spend the time answering the question. As soon as you figure out the answer you should be responding so we don't spend time answering a question that has already been answered.

Comment: I was going to post an answer later, but you are right. Sorry about that.